# Select empty column if regexp_match fails

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to select all entities, even if they're not match expression, but this one returns only 'true' values.

```
SELECT entity_id, regexp_matches(error_params, '"select_flight"') IS NOT NULL
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY 1
```

Is there a way do solve such issue inside `SELECT` statement or in this case we should use `LEFT JOIN` to table with `regexp_matches` result?

Comment: why do you need a `group by` here?

Comment: @vkp, I want to select all `entity_id`'s and count of regular expression that were matched in column `error_params` inside `MyTable`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  Not sure you need `regexp_matches` but difficult to understand your question.  And if you want `count`, then you'll need to use `count`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `count` with `case`:

```
select entity_id,
       count(case when error_params like '%select flight%' then 1 end) cnt
from mytable
group by 1
```

Comment: thank you for this idea, I tried to use `count(case when error_params ~ 'regexp' then 1 end)` and it works fine for me.